# service autostart in Linux after system reboot

Tags: linux, service, startup

Hello guys need some assistance upon how to make services auto start upon system boot in CentOS (Linux). In particular I am talking about tomcat and radius I have scripts but not sure where to place those, maybe you will advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you need to edit is **/etc/rc.d/rc.local** (or /etc/rc.local for Debian-based systems)
just add:

/path/to/yourScript.sh

Save the file and restart!
More details in this forum response:
[LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/auto-execute-shell-script-on-startup-294891/)